# Is there a dev-server tunnel in Webpack 2?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently looking for solution to test my frontend stuff on my mobile phone. Like browsersync on gulp. Thank you, guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel 
Look this package. Install global and share any port what you want.